# Search/replace words beetween custom tags by asterisks with python regex

Tags: python, regex

In python 3, I have a string :

```
CONN <DO_NOT_PRINT>user</DO_NOT_PRINT>/<DO_NOT_PRINT>password</DO_NOT_PRINT>@//host:port/service
```

I want to replace each letter in the words beetween <DO_NOT_PRINT> and </DO_NOT_PRINT> tags by asterisks (and remove the tags), ie :

```
CONN ****/********@//host:port/service
```

strings user and especially password can be any chars

What I have so far is :

```
z="CONN <DO_NOT_PRINT>user</DO_NOT_PRINT>/<DO_NOT_PRINT>password</DO_NOT_PRINT>@//host:port/service"
REPLACEME = re.compile('<DO_NOT_PRINT>(.+)<\/DO_NOT_PRINT>')
found = REPLACEME.search(z)
print(found)
if found:
    old_text = found.group(1)
    new_z = z.replace(old_text, '*' * len(old_text))
    print(new_z)
else:
    print(z)
```

but it doesn't work correctly as it prints :

```
CONN <DO_NOT_PRINT>******************************************</DO_NOT_PRINT>@//host:port/service
```

instead of :

```
CONN ****/********@//host:port/service
```

Comment: Please let me know if you read the message above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
z="CONN <DO_NOT_PRINT>user</DO_NOT_PRINT>/<DO_NOT_PRINT>password</DO_NOT_PRINT>@//host:port/service"
REPLACEME = re.compile('<DO_NOT_PRINT>(.*?)</DO_NOT_PRINT>', re.DOTALL)
print( REPLACEME.sub(lambda x: '*' * len(x.group(1)), z) )
    
# => CONN ****/********@//host:port/service
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gCRczh).

**NOTES**:

- `re.compile(r'<DO_NOT_PRINT>(.*?)</DO_NOT_PRINT>', re.DOTALL)` -  `*?` lazy quantifier is used to make sure the matching stops at the leftmost occurrence of the right-hand delimiter and `re.DOTALL` makes sure `.` matches line break chars, too
- `lambda x: '*' * len(x.group(1))` is now the `re.sub` replacement argument, where `x` is the `MatchData` object, `x.group(1)` is the Group 1 captured value, the text between two strings.

If you are concerned with performance, unroll the lazy dot pattern:

```py
REPLACEME = re.compile(r'<DO_NOT_PRINT>([^<]*(?:<(?!/DO_NOT_PRINT>)[^<]*)*)</DO_NOT_PRINT>')
```

Do not use `re.DOTALL` here.

Answer (score 2):

Regex tries to match with the longest value possible, so the `(.+)` captures:

```
user</DO_NOT_PRINT>/<DO_NOT_PRINT>password
```

You should specify ungreedy operator after plus:

```py
REPLACEME = re.compile('<DO_NOT_PRINT>(.+?)<\/DO_NOT_PRINT>')
```

Your `group(1)` does not encompass `<DO_NOT_PRINT>`. If you want this to also disappear, use `group(0)` to get the entire matched string. Try:

```py
z.replace(found.group(0), '*' * len(old_text))
```

*Edit*:

If you want to replace multiple occurance, you can use `re.finditer()` and do one `.replace()` for each match: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer

```py
import re
z="CONN <DO_NOT_PRINT>user</DO_NOT_PRINT>/<DO_NOT_PRINT>password</DO_NOT_PRINT>@//host:port/service"
REPLACEME = re.compile('<DO_NOT_PRINT>(.+?)<\/DO_NOT_PRINT>')
founds = REPLACEME.finditer(z)
print(founds)
for found in founds:
    old_text = found.group(1)
    z = z.replace(found.group(0), '*' * len(old_text))
print(z)
```

Or, use Viktor's answer which looks more elegant.

Comment: Thanks, it works better with ungreedy operator but it still replace only the first occurence.

I also changed 
    new_z = z.replace(old_text, '*' * len(old_text))
to
    new_z = z.replace(f"<DO_NOT_PRINT>{old_text}</DO_NOT_PRINT>", '*' * len(old_text))